# Scala Slick - Identify which DBIO is failing in DBIO.sequence

Tags: scala, slick, scala-cats

I'm executing transactionally 3 different operations on DB in the following way

```
// firstDBIO, secondDBIOA, thirdDBIO: DBIOAction[Unit]

F.delay {
  val unitOfWork = DBIO.sequence(
    List(
      firstDBIO,
      secondDBIO,
      thirdDBIO,
    ),
  )
  db.run(unitOfWork.transactionally)
}.futureLift.void.map(_.asRight[ImportError]).recover {
  case ex: SQLException => Left(ImportError.UnexpectedError)
}
```

This works correctly but, when the transaction fails, in the `recover` I can't make logic based on which of the `DBIO` caused the error (I don't want to rely on the `SQLException`).

I would like to be able to do something like

```
.recover {
  case ex: ImportError.CauseFirst => ...
  case ex: ImportError.CauseSecond => ...
  case ex: ImportError.CauseThird => ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this solution is exactly what I was looking for

```
dbio.asTry.flatMap {
  case Success(v) => DBIO.successful(v)
  case Failure(e) => DBIO.failed(ImportError.CauseFirst)
}
```

It preserves the success/failure outcome triggering the abortion of the atomic transaction as requested.
In the end, it's just mapping the error contained in the failure, indeed it's quite useful to implement a function to do that

```
implicit class DBIOOps[A](dbio: DBIO[A]) {
  def mapFailure(f: Throwable => E with Throwable) = dbio.asTry.flatMap {
    case Success(v) => DBIO.successful(v)
    case Failure(e) => DBIO.failed(f(e))
  }
}
```

```
F.delay {
  val unitOfWork = DBIO.sequence(
    List(
      firstDBIO.mapFailure(_ => ImportError.CauseFirst),
      secondDBIO.mapFailure(_ => ImportError.CauseSecond),
      thirdDBIO.mapFailure(_ => ImportError.CauseThird),
      ...
    ),
  )
  db.run(unitOfWork.transactionally)
}.futureLift.void.map(_.asRight[ImportError]).recover {
  case ex: ImportError.CauseFirst => ...
  case ex: ImportError.CauseSecond => ...
  case ex: ImportError.CauseThird => ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `.sequence` then you'll just fail on the first failed future. You have 2 options:

- map each DBIO's error to contain the number - I guess you could abuse `.cleanUp` method with something like

  ```
  dbio.cleanUp({
    case Some(error) => DBIO.failed(improveError(error)) // add idx to Exception or sth
    case None => DBIO.successful(())
  }, keepFailure = false)
  ```
- preserve individual results as `Try` and resolve them after transaction

  ```
  dbio.asTry
  // then use db.run(DBIO.sequence(dbios).transactionally)
  // to get Future[List[Try[Int]]]
  ```

I am not sure how the latter would handle transactions and rollbacks compared to the former, but both cases would let you find out which action failed.

Comment: The solution with Try will no longer abort after the first failure, which could be a problem.

Comment: Would be nice if there was a `fold`, `mapError` or `recoverWith` in DBIO, but according to their documentation using `cleanUp` to transform the throwable is indeed an intended use-case. So no abuse here ;-)